# Spark Streaming data to update SQL Server (transaction)

Tags: sql-server, spark-streaming

Currently I have some pyspark code, which is reading data (readStream) from kafka topic and I'm planning on updating a SQL Server table using a transaction. Stream data would have all three INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE transactions.

Could you please suggest best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide further information to clarify your question, such as the pyspark code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Reading Kafka topic through Pyspark code and updating the events (Insert, Update, Delete) in SQL server will not be the right approach what I feel.

**Reason for why?**

Consider Insert event is occurring in Kafka. 
In this scenario, respective key will not be available in target table and could be written directly in target table without any issue. 
But when you are handling other events (Update and delete) from Kafka. We can’t write it in Target table directly without comparing existing key value. To compare that key value, whole data set need to be brought back into memory as data frame or RDD (As we aware, pyspark is running in memory) for comparison and overwrite target table. Handling whole target table records In-memory will not be right approach.

**Alternate solution:** We can choose Cassandra for this solution as C* is working Upsert mode. But Cassandra data modeling is not same as SQL server.

Comment: From a database perspective, the best way to do this would be to pass the dataset to SQL and let it work out what needs to inserted/updated (delete is another matter). Can you comment on whether pyspark can call a T-SQL stored procedure (with some kind of parameter representing the data)? Then you can wrap up the transaction and merge logic in that without needing chatty data operations between DB and spark server.